# Where are wordpress post formats stored within db?

Tags: wordpress, magento

I'm using Fishpig's magento extension and looking to include the post format as a data element on the Post model, however by default it is not included.

I need to modify the code to also look for this value.

I've taken a look at postmeta and I don't see any changes when i change the post formats.

Where is the relationship between wp_posts and their format?

Answer (score 3):

The relationship is a pivot between wp_posts -> wp_term_relationships <- wp_terms

For those interested in accessing post formats this through the fishpig magento wordpress extension you can use this as a starting point:

within: app\code\community\Fishpig\Wordpress\Model\Post.php
edit the method getPostFormat

```
public function getPostFormat()
{
        return Mage::getResourceModel('wordpress/term_collection')
        ->addTaxonomyFilter('post_format')
        ->addPostIdFilter($this->getId())
        ->getFirstItem()
        ->getData('name');
}
```

and then you can call from within your post list/view template:

`echo $post->getPostFormat()`
and do something with it